# Pushing complete span down when element is overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having the following code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 relative">
    <div id="contactinfo" class="text-white">
        <span>client name</span> – 
        <span><a href="mail@something" class="text-green">mail@something</a></span> – 
        <span>01 23456789</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I resize my screen to a certain point, the phonenumber (since its now displayed all next to each other) i'd like to, when my the phonenumber is broken up, to a new line. Right now, whenever it wont fit anymore, it will move only the 23456789 part because thats what technically overflows, but I want the whole element to move down, so it wont break the appearance of the phonenumber. Is this possible?

This is a bootply of it. http://www.bootply.com/RFVcvXGRmP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on this span :

[See it here](http://www.bootply.com/rgNzd8Npwx)

Comment: God, i feel so silly. To not think of that. Thanks. Accepting it as answer whenever I can. The whole reason I didnt thought of it, was simply because I thought a span was automaticly an inline-block. Not sure where I got that from, cause now i realize span is an inline element.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome :) 
I don't think there's any element which is a native `inline-block` element so it helps when you are not sure :)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to change the `initial` display value for the `<span>` element you can use the `white-space` rule with `nowrap`. This is actually what it was made for.

> [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> The white-space property is used to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled.
>
> **nowrap**
>
> *Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.*

```
#contactinfo span:nth-child(3) { 
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
```

I know that there is already an accepted answer, just adding this for the record.

Comment: More precisely:

#contactinfo span:nth-child(3) {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ll take it along next time. The inline-block solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Instead of 3 span you need to take only two span like
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 relative">
    <div id="contactinfo" class="text-white">
        <span>client name</span> – 

        <span><a href="mail@something" class="text-green">mail@something</a>-01 23456789</span>
    </div>
</div>

and one changes in css
<style>
  #contactinfo span{display:inline-block;}
 </style>
```

Comment: There are 3 spans for a reason, since it seperates the elements (name /  email ./phone. I am not changing that setup. Thanks for the thought, but its not the answer i was looking for. I specificly asked for that one span, not for a merger of 2 spans into one, cause the email will be pushed down as well in your answer, which is not what i want.